# Launch Portable Google Chrome with supplied parameters from flash drive on Mac OSX

Tags: google-chrome, parameters, portability, chromium, portable-applications

As the title suggests, I want to write a shell command to open google chrome portable (with supplied parameter) which is installed on the flash drive also. I am trying to do it as follows:

```
open "/Volumes/NDCS/chrome/chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Portable Chromium" --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Portable Chrome opens up, but the setting hasn't worked. I also wanted it to launch a default homepage (parameter is --homepage="[url or file path]", but for now have done that by setting the default homepage in the browser.

If anyone has any knowledge/advice on this, would be much appreciated. I have done the same scenario on PC recently, just struggling with the Mac deployment.

Answer (score 0):

From man open you need to supply thr parameters to the executable using the --args argument, otherwise they are taken as arguments to open not the app.

Also Open works on the App bundle
So

```
open "/Volumes/NDCS/chrome/chromium.app" --args --allow-file-access-from-files
```

oruse the plain unix executable as you are doinf without the open

```
"/Volumes/NDCS/chrome/chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Portable Chromium" --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Comment: Hi Mark, appreciate your quick response. I have tried the --args argument - although good to know it is necessary and needs to stay in. I am trying the following at the moment as a quick test... open "/Volumes/NDCS/chrome/chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Portable Chromium" --args --homepage="http://www.google.co.uk" - any ideas what might be wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Still really stuck on this one and needing a solution fast. I'm using portable chrome 13.0.782.218 (98754) on OS X 10.7. Should the switches work on this version of portable chrome? I can't get any switches to work. I can't also find another solution. The reason I need to supply the switch (mentioned above) is that I am accessing a local JSON file via JQuery GetJSON, which google blocks for security reasons. Adding this parameter resolved the problem fine on my PC Deployment of the same app.